# Xamarin Android Forms designer does not recognize GridLayout layout parameters

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm designing a form using a table layout, but the compiler is complaining that a number of attributes are either not defined or not allowed. Here's a snippet of the layout:

```xml
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/player1Layout"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="1" />
```

When I compile, I get both warnings and errors related to the `layout_*` attributes. For the moment, I've set all three API levels (compile, target, and minimum) 26, which I'm pretty sure has all of these attributes, but I get the following errors:

```
error APT0000: 1: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_margin' with value '1').
error APT0000: 1: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_margin' with value '1').
error APT0000: 1: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_margin' with value '1').
error APT0000: 1: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_margin' with value '1').

The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_column' attribute is not declared.
The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_row' attribute is not declared.
The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_columnWeight' attribute is not declared.
The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_rowWeight' attribute is not declared.
```

Comment: your error for for the 'layout_margin' is Integer types not allowed, Yes it allows  density-independent points.... something like this android:layout_marginRight="1dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error APT0000: 1: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_margin' with value '1').

Use `dp` units, i.e.:

```
android:layout_margin="1dp"
```

Comment: huh. odd; I set it through the designer UI and it correctly updated the WYSIWYG rendering.